# setVisible() does not hide the node

Tags: java, javafx

I have the LineChart with 4 different series. There are checkboxes which should show/hide the correspondent series from chart. But when I pressed checkboxes for "Euler", "Improved Euler", "Runge-Kutta", they do not affect the chart at all, until I press the "Exact"'s checkbox. Can't get the problem absolutely.

Here is how I try to hide/show:

```
@FXML private NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
@FXML private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
@FXML private LineChart<Number, Number> chartAll = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> exactSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> eulerSeries= new XYChart.Series<>();
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> improvedEulerSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> rungeKuttaSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();

@FXML private CheckBox exactChartCheckbox;
@FXML private CheckBox eulerChartCheckbox;
@FXML private CheckBox improvedEulerChartCheckbox;
@FXML private CheckBox rungeKuttaChartCheckbox;

@FXML
protected void handlePlotButton(ActionEvent event) {
    chartAll.getData().clear();
    double x0 = Double.parseDouble(x0Input.getText());
    double y0 = Double.parseDouble(y0Input.getText());
    double x = Double.parseDouble(xInput.getText());
    double step = Double.parseDouble(stepInput.getText());
    IVP ivpForExact = new IVP(x0, y0, x, step);
    Exact exact = new Exact(ivpForExact);
    Euler euler = new Euler(ivpForExact);
    ImprovedEuler improvedEuler = new ImprovedEuler(ivpForExact);
    RungeKutta rungeKutta = new RungeKutta(ivpForExact);
    exactSeries.setName("Exact");
    eulerSeries.setName("Euler");
    improvedEulerSeries.setName("Improved Euler");
    rungeKuttaSeries.setName("Runge-Kutta");
    for (int i = 0; i < exact.getGrid().getSize(); i++) {
        exactSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(exact.getGrid().getXat(i), exact.getGrid().getYat(i)));
        eulerSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(euler.getGrid().getXat(i), euler.getGrid().getYat(i)));
        improvedEulerSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(improvedEuler.getGrid().getXat(i), improvedEuler.getGrid().getYat(i)));
        rungeKuttaSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(rungeKutta.getGrid().getXat(i), rungeKutta.getGrid().getYat(i)));
    }
    chartAll.getData().add(exactSeries);
    chartAll.getData().add(eulerSeries);
    chartAll.getData().add(improvedEulerSeries);
    chartAll.getData().add(rungeKuttaSeries);
    stepInput.clear();
    }

@FXML
protected void exactChartCheckboxPressed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(!exactChartCheckbox.isSelected()) {
        chartAll.getData().get(0).getNode().setVisible(false);
    } else {
        chartAll.getData().get(0).getNode().setVisible(true);
    }
}

@FXML
protected void eulerChartCheckboxPressed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(!eulerChartCheckbox.isSelected()) {
        chartAll.getData().get(1).getNode().setVisible(false);
    } else {
        chartAll.getData().get(1).getNode().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane fx:id="scene" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1080.0">
            <children>
                <LineChart fx:id="chartAll" createSymbols="false" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="135.0" prefHeight="427.0" prefWidth="698.0">
                    <xAxis>
                        <NumberAxis label="x" fx:id="xAxis" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                        <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" autoRanging="false" label="y" lowerBound="-10.0" upperBound="40.0" />
                    </yAxis>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
                </LineChart>
                <Button layoutX="48.0" layoutY="54.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Solutions" />
                <TextField layoutX="883.0" layoutY="211.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="0" fx:id="x0Input" />
                <TextField fx:id="y0Input" layoutX="883.0" layoutY="254.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="3" />
                <TextField layoutX="883.0" layoutY="296.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="5.5" fx:id="xInput" />
                <TextField fx:id="stepInput" layoutX="883.0" layoutY="336.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="0.1" />
                <Label layoutX="841.0" layoutY="215.0" text="x0" />
                <Label layoutX="841.0" layoutY="258.0" text="y0" />
                <Label layoutX="841.0" layoutY="300.0" text="X" />
                <Label layoutX="835.0" layoutY="340.0" text="step" />
                <Button fx:id="plotButton" layoutX="896.0" layoutY="385.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlotButton" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="Plot" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="exactChartCheckbox" layoutX="347.0" layoutY="562.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exactChartCheckboxPressed" selected="true" text="Exact" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="improvedEulerChartCheckbox" layoutX="523.0" layoutY="562.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#improvedEulerChartCheckboxPressed" selected="true" text="Improved Euler" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="rungeKuttaChartCheckbox" layoutX="646.0" layoutY="562.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#rungeKuttaChartCheckboxPressed" selected="true" text="Runge-Kutta" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="eulerChartCheckbox" layoutX="444.0" layoutY="562.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eulerChartCheckboxPressed" selected="true" text="Euler" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Here is the result

after I hide firstly "Euler" and then "Exact":
[image: after I hide firstly "Euler" and then "Exact"]

after I show "Exact" then "Euler":
[image: after I show "Exact" then "Euler"]

The problem actually is that chart is only updated when I check/uncheck "Exact" box, all three others do not affect the chart. But when I press the "Exact"'s checkbox, they are trying to be updated also but do it improperly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the problem from what you've given. Try to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question. While creating the MCVE you might even find the solution.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your FXML file. Also, are you saying only the 'exact' handler works? The 'euler' does not work? Or are you sayin the 'euler' only works after the 'exact' has done its job? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

To effectively hide the node try setting the managed property

```
series.getNode().setManaged(false);
```

> Defines whether or not this node's layout will be managed by it's parent. If the node is managed, it's parent will factor the node's geometry into its own preferred size and layoutBounds calculations and will lay it out during the scene's layout pass. If a managed node's layoutBounds changes, it will automatically trigger relayout up the scene-graph to the nearest layout root (which is typically the scene's root node).
>
> If the node is unmanaged, its parent will ignore the child in both preferred size computations and layout. Changes in layoutBounds will not trigger relayout above it. If an unmanaged node is of type Parent, it will act as a "layout root", meaning that calls to Parent.requestLayout() beneath it will cause only the branch rooted by the node to be relayed out, thereby isolating layout changes to that root and below. It's the application's responsibility to set the size and position of an unmanaged node.

Comment: Unfortunately, setManaged() is not connected by anyway with rendering charts thus doesnot help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the length of my comment, I am posting it in answer rather than in comment.

Firstly, if you check the documentation of ***node*** in XYChart.Series

> The node to display for this series. This is created by the chart if
>   it uses nodes to represent the whole series. For example line chart
>   uses this for the line but scatter chart does not use it. This node
>   will be set as soon as the series is added to the chart. You can then
>   get it to add mouse listeners etc.

From the above, it is clear that you can easily rely on node if it is line chart. And from your screenshot I can see that you are already using LineChart. Which is not a problem. If you inspect the node type, it will be of type Path. But things get a little messy if your line chart has data points displayed on it.Sometimes toggling the node(Path) visibility alone cannot get the desired behavior. For example check the below screen shot.

[image]

So to hide a series from the chart, I would recommend **to add/remove the series from the data** rather than toggling the visibility of the series node.

Coming to your problem, I gave a quick check to toggle the lines visiblity and it working fine for all series. Might be some issue in your code. As @Slaw mentioned, a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can help us to understand the issue or even solve your problem by yourself.

Comment: There is a problem with add/remove, when I press checkbox faster than one time/second, it throws "Dupicate series added" exception, and it appears from using different threads for code and for event handling, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, like it depends on your luck or some legacy JavaFX code. When I changed each series to Array of series:

```
private ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> exactSeries = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> eulerSeries = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> improvedEulerSeries = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> rungeKuttaSeries = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then create the common function for all cases:

```
private void turnVisibility(CheckBox checkBox, ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> seriesList) {
    if (!checkBox.isSelected()) {
        for(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series: seriesList) {
            series.getNode().setVisible(false);
        }
    } else {
        for(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series: seriesList) {
            series.getNode().setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

visibility starts work correctly.